# Connect to VPN from GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

In my local network I have a VPN endpoint, into which I normally connect via VPNC. Now I would like to be able to call into the network from GCP. Is there any way of doing this?

Preferably without having to launch a whole VM instance...

Comment: GCP has VPN technology to allow you to create a VPN between your local end and the GCP VPC Network ... see ... https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/   This uses IPsec.  Does VPNC support IPsec?  From a web surf, it seems VPNC is for Cisco devices.  Perhaps install an IPsec client on your local network if VPNC doesn't support IPsec?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use Cisco's VPNC Client to connect to Google Cloud VPNs. Google Cloud VPNs only support site-to-site setups. No VPN client support is provided.

You have several options. First using the traditional VPN site-to-site connectivity. This is only supported on certain hardware VPN/routers. Unless you have a good background in VPNs this method is challenging.

You can also use a software site-to-site VPN using OpenSwan. This requires one computer in GCP and another computer in your network. This works well and is not hard to setup.

If you only need connectivity from your desktop to Google Cloud, use a software product called OpenVPN. I deploy this solution often and it works very well. This requires a computer running in the cloud and a client that you install on your desktop.

In your question, you mention that you do not want to set up a whole VM. Google Cloud VPNs are expensive compared to a standalone F1-micro instance which is enough to run a good bandwidth software VPN. There is no free VPN in Google Cloud.